# How can I deep copy in typescript

Tags: jquery, typescript

I have object in typescript:

```
export class A {
 public var1: boolean = false;
 public var2: boolean = false;
 public b: B = new B();
```

}

```
export class B {
   public v: boolean = false;
}
```

And declare and exist object:

```
...
public a: A = new A();
...
```

When I use jQuery:

```
const myCopy: A = $.extend(true, {}, this.a);
this.a.b.v = true;
```

When I change variable object this.a  I see change in copy.
How Can I deep copy in this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use triple ...

```
let b = new A();
const mCopy = {...b};
```

or you can use json stringify and json parse

`const mCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(target`));

Comment: Still, when it changes boolean to true in the object (B) of the original object (A ),in the copy I see this change.

Comment: you can try json stringify and json parse

Comment: Spread doesn't do a deep copy.

Comment: Would `const mCopy = Object.assign({}, b}` also work ? I've seen it in the wild

Comment: @SamuelPrevost You posted this 2+ years ago, so I'm sure you know the answer now, but for those who don't and stumble here: Object.assign({}, b} does a shallow copy just like {...b}.